# Text input Regex for m:ss time format is buggy in Vue, for any minute at or above 6

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, substr

I am trying to have validation that prevents the user from typing invalid numbers for this time format m:ss (m = minute, s = seconds).

I.E) 1 minute and 30 seconds = 1:30, 1 minute and 59 seconds 1:59.
This would not be allowed: 1:61 or 1:77, since those are not valid seconds.

The first s can only be values 0-5, the second s and m can be 0-9

In Vue I have this in the text input box

```
            <div>
               <input
                  v-model="formatTime"
                  id="time-input"
                  type="text"
               />
            </div>
```

I have this in watch:

```
 watch: {
   formatTime () {
      const totalLength = this.formatTime.length;
      let a = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
        .substr(0, 1);

      const b = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-5]/g, "")
        .substr(1, 1);

      const c = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
        .substr(2, 1);
      if (totalLength >= 2) {
        a = `${a.substring(0, 1)}:${b}${c}`;
      }
      this.formatTime = a;
    },
}
```

The values work when I type numbers 1:11 to 5:55.
But the bug is when I try to type 6-9 first, I can't type any other number after

I.E) I try to type 6:11 -> I get stuck on 6: and can't type any valid number.
I can't even type 6:11, when that should be valid.

Happens when I try to type 7:10, 8:44, 9:11. Anything 6 and above, it gets stuck at the first number.

I don't know what the problem is since 1:44, or 5:59 works. The regex looks right to me, but maybe it's something with the logic or substr?

Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the regular expression in this line:

```js
const b = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-5]/g, "")  // 1. remove anything not 0 through 5
  .substr(1, 1);                                  // 2. take 2nd character of result
```

Assume a key sequence of `789`...

1. **Keypress 1:** `7` is *inside* the character class range (thus *not removed*), so **`a` is `7`**.
2. **Keypress 2:** `7` and `8` are *outside* the character class range, so they're *removed* from the string. The 2nd character of an empty string is still empty, so **`b` is the empty string**.
3. **Keypress 3:** `7` and `8` are *inside* the character class range (thus *not removed*). The result is only two characters long because the preceding keypress got stripped above, so the 3rd character does not exist, and **`c` is the empty string**.
4. Finally, it gets assembled with a delimiter (`${a}:${b}${c}`), resulting in `7:`.

#### Solution

One way to fix this is for the second replacement to remove *all* non-digits, and then limit the 2nd digit to `5`.

```js
let b = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").substr(1, 1);
if (b > 5) b = 5;
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjWKWRO?editors=1010)