# How to store formatted input text into an array with indexes in Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, format

This is an extension from this question [Vue.js: Input formatting using computed property is not applying when typing quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560456/vue-js-input-formatting-using-computed-property-is-not-applying-when-typing-qui)

I am stuck on how to get a list of formatted values from my text input into an array list.
I need to do this in a matrix, but simplified it into an array.

Please help, thank you!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <div
      v-for="(input, index) in valueInputs" <-- index
      :key="index"
    >
      <input
        v-model="value"     // <-- I want to track what index I'm in
        @input="formatTime" // <-- so I can set it in an array later
        maxLength="4"       // I tried formatTime[index] or value[index]
        id="format-value" // but that doesn't work, how to pass index 
        class="input" // into formatTime or value fields?
        type="text"
      />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
data () {
  return {
  valueInputs: [],    // a list of inputs
  allFormatValues: [] // want to store all the formatted values here by the index
 }
}
```

Want to set an array that stores all the formatted values:

```
   this.allFormatValues[index] = this.value;
```

I'm not sure how to associate the index with the formatted string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving the values of `valueInputs` array not its indexs. However, you can get the index of each value in `v-for` as follows:

```
v-for="(value, index) in valueInputs"
```

Comment: Ah I simplified the code, but yes I already `v-for="(value, index) in valueInputs"` in the code. But the problem is I can't pass the index into the input tag v-model="value" or @input="formatTime"

Comment: You can pass it as a parameter to formatTime function. `@input="formatTime(index)"` or `@input="formatTime(value, index)"` if you need both in you function. Just make sure to change formatTime code accordingly though.

Comment: Thanks, the code in the link actually didn't work in my case.  Sorry I think I wasn't clear. I have to use watches for it to work from the below link, so I do't know how to add indexes here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551738/text-input-regex-for-mss-time-format-is-buggy-in-vue-for-any-minute-at-or-abov/67552069#67552069

Comment: Will `valueInputs` array be filled in by users?

Comment: Yes, a user will be able to add more days and its stored there

Comment: What is the length of `valueInputs` array then?

Comment: It varies, depending on how many the user adds

Comment: But you cant use `v-for` to loop through an empty array

Comment: sorry I mean there is one at the very beginning, but then the user can add as many as they want afterwards

Comment: Do you mean the input fields are increased by 1 every time the user adds a new input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232513/discussion-between-suzy-and-llro-dasmaz).